# Keyword not supported in SQL Server CE connection string

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server CE database in a C# web application (VB 2012) using this connection string:

```
using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source|DataDirectory|\MyData.sdf; Persist Security Info=False;"))
```

The problem is that I am getting an exception that the `data source|datadirectory` is not a supported keyword. I attempted to change this string to:

```
Data Source=MainDb.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;
```

But then I get an error that the Db cannot be found. The database is located in the `App_Data` folder. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're just simply missing an `=` sign:

```
Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyData.sdf; Persist Security Info=False;
           * 
          ***
```

Comment: That's it! Sorry for the stupid mistake.

Comment: Happens to all of us - just too deep into a problem, you cannot see the simplest typos.... glad this solved your problem!

Comment: As Mariner 1 programmers know only too well, @marc_s. =)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax seems to be incorrect - it should look something like this:

> using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source =
>   |DataDirectory|\MyData.sdf; Persist Security Info=False;"))